# Dose objc_release / objc_retain thread safe?

Tags: objective-c

A Class Property, Such as:

```
@interface TestModel
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *testStr;
@end
```

At main Thread:

```
for (model in modellist) {
    if ((!model.testStr || ![model.testStr isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] || model.testStr.length == 0)) {
         NSLog(@"empty str");
    }
    NSLog(@"not empty str");
}
```

At BackGround Thread:

```
for (model in modellist) {
    model.testStr = anotherStringFromAlloc
}
```

At main thread:Only read property

At backGround thread: Write property content

Is this thread safe?

After read some source code, I have another question is:
Dose objc_retain and objc_release same obj is thread safe ?

Comment: The atomicity is there to allow you to safely use the returned `NSString` from the property without fear of it being released out from under you as a result of an assignment. If you're asking if the code is 'thread safe', under the very limited use you're using in this example code, it *will work*, but if you want to make use of the returned property for anything other than a `NULL` check, it needs to be atomic to keep it safe. In relation to your other question - [it's already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512540/thread-safe-retain-release).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Petesh notes, this question is mostly answered in [thread-safe retain/release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512540/thread-safe-retain-release), but I think just duping there will miss answering your specific problem.

You've explicitly asked for this property *not* to be thread-safe:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *testStr;
```

The default behavior is `atomic`, which make it safe to read and write *the pointer* (not mutate the object) on different threads. You've marked this `nonatomic`, which disables that behavior. For more on this, see bbum's fairly [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589392/97337) on `atomic`.

Your code, though, is also a good example of how relying on atomic reads alone to make code "thread-safe" can go wrong. This line is very unsafe:

```
if ((!model.testStr || ![model.testStr isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] || model.testStr.length == 0)) {
```

This makes three separate reads of `model.testStr`. Even with `atomic`, there's no promise that these are the same object if you might modify this on another thread. The fact that you test the class suggests that `testStr` might be something other than an NSString. If so, then `model.testStr.length` may crash with "does not respond to selector." If you use `model.testStr` inside the `if` block, then that may also be a different value than you tested.

Comment: Helped me a lot，Specifically pointed out that atmoic only ensure getter thread safe，there is no guarantee that logic is correct